# difficulty in reshaping a numpy array while working with images

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, image-processing

While creating a GUI for a digit recognition model, I am working with images using openCV and numPy. I am sort of stuck at this situation where I have got, say an image having shape as (8,8,3). I want to get it in a shape of (8,8), so that I could feed it to my classifier model so it could categorize it. Take it this way, I want the third dimension (i.e. 3) to be dropped off. Could someone please guide me through this?
I have also attached the code snippet for the same scenario wherein I am receiving an error :

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
img = cv.imread("1.png")
output = cv.imshow("Image: ", img)
cv.waitKey(0)
arr = np.array(img)
new_arr = arr.reshape((8,8))   #trying to reshape it into (8,8)   {don't want that ugly looking '3' at last}
print(arr.shape)               #shape of original image = (8,8,3)
print(arr)
print(new_arr)
```

And, the error I am getting is as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ----> new_arr = arr.reshape((8, 8))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 192 into shape (8,8)
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reshape cannot change the total number of elements in the array.  You are trying to 'throw-away' 2/3 of the data.  That `3` isn't "ugly" - it's the color dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be achieved by the reshape method. Look at it this way to understand, the reshape cannot reshape input data to smaller or bigger size because there would be loss of data.

You are asking the reshape method to rearrange `8*8*3` numbers to a data type which can have `8*8` numbers, thus, it will definitely throw an error because it is not programmed to lose information(in this case 8*8*2 numbers).

You can convert the image of size `8*8*3` to `8*8` without losing information by converting the image to grayscale. Generally `3` in `8*8*3` represents the number of channels in the image. Grayscale image contains the `1` channel only, thus, it is the best way to solve your problem.

You can convert image to grayscale by using this code:

```py
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

`img` will now be of size `8*8`.